# What is a good way to bind a SwiftUI alert or action sheet to the optionality of a value type model property (show the view when the property is nil)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI alerts and action sheets take Boolean bindings, but I want mine to display when a model property is `nil`. The model property is `var servicePlayer: Player!`, and I want an alert or action sheet to be presented when the tennis serving player is not yet selected (`nil`), but I'm not sure what would be a good way to approach this.

My model layer is composed of value type `struct`s, so at the moment marking the property as `@Published` isn't an option. It doesn't sound worth it refactoring my whole model layer to a `class` reference type to be able to adopt Combine (I depend on the model instances being value type copies for undoing and redoing), but I may be wrong.

```
struct Match: Codable {
    ...
    var servicePlayer: Player!
    ...
}

.alert(isPresented: $isPresented) {
    Alert(title: Text("Who will serve?"),
              primaryButton: .default(Text("You")) {
                match.servicePlayer = .playerOne
            },
              secondaryButton: .default(Text("Opponent")) {
                match.servicePlayer = .playerTwo
            })
}
```

The `$isPresented` binding is just a placeholder. Since `servicePlayer` starts out `nil`, the idea is for the alert to be initially presented, but also reappear later in the tennis match when service player is `nil` again and yet to be selected.

Comment: It would be best if you showed some minimal code

Comment: @NewDev I just added the relevant parts of the code, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you probably understand, the `isPresented` parameter of `.alert` requires a `Binding<Bool>`.

I assume `Match` is a `@State` property in your view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var match: Match

   var body: some View { ... }
}
```

which means that when that changes, the view will recompute. This means that your particular case you can use `Binding.constant(bool)`:

```
.alert(isPresented: .constant(match.servicePlayer == nil)) {
   Alert(...)
}
```

because the `Alert` will modify the state by changing `match`.